# Extending ASP.NET Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

I am trying to create a new Service Control extending the ASP.NET panel.

Howwever whenever I use my panel, the divs etc render correctly.
But the input in the box is only : [title]

ie: if i do:

```
<cc1:RoundedCornerBox id="MyBox" BoxWidth="100" BoxHeight="200"> This is the content that   should be displayeed </cc1:RoundedBox>
```

all that is displayed is: 
 [MyBox]

(in a box that is correct)

This is my code:

```
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:RoundedCornerBox runat=server></{0}:RoundedCornerBox>")]
public class RoundedCornerBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel
{

public int BoxWidth { get; set; }
public int BoxHeight { get; set; }


[Bindable(true)]
[Category("Appearance")]
[DefaultValue("")]
[Localizable(true)]
public string Text
{
    get
    {
        String s = (String)ViewState["Text"];
        return ((s == null) ? "[" + this.ID + "]" : s);
    }

    set
    {
        ViewState["Text"] = value;
    }
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.Render(writer);
}
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
    output.Write(Text);
}


public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.RenderBeginTag(writer);
    writer.Write("<div class=\"roundedcornr_lt\"></div>\n");
    writer.Write("<div class=\"roundedcornr_top\" style=\"width:" + BoxWidth.ToString() + "px\"></div>\n");
    writer.Write("<div class=\"roundedcornr_rt\"></div>\n");
    writer.Write("<div class=\"clear\"></div>\n");
    writer.Write("<div class=\"roundedcornr_lside\" style=\"height:" + BoxHeight.ToString() + "px\"></div>\n");
    writer.Write("<div style=\"width:" + BoxWidth.ToString() + "px; height:" + BoxHeight.ToString() + "px; background:white; float:left\">\n");



}

public override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.RenderEndTag(writer);
    writer.Write("</div>\n");
    writer.Write("<div class=\"roundedcornr_rside\" style=\"height:" + BoxHeight.ToString() + "px\"></div>\n");
    writer.Write("<div class=\"clear\"></div>\n");
    writer.Write("<div class=\"roundedcornr_bl\"></div>\n");
    writer.Write("<div class=\"roundedcornr_btm\" style=\"width:" + BoxWidth.ToString() + "px\"></div>");
    writer.Write("<div class=\"roundedcornr_br\"></div>");
    writer.Write("<div class=\"clear\"></div>\n");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would inherit Label, you would do it this way:

```
        get
        {
            string result = (string) ViewState["Text"];
            if(result != null)
                return result;
            result = (string) base.Text;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                return result;
            return "[" + this.ID + "]";
        }
```

Unfortunately there is no "normal" way to get the inner text of a Panel, but this is a workaround:

```
        get
        {
            string result = (string) ViewState["Text"];
            if(result != null)
                return result;
            result = ((LiteralControl) this.Controls[0]).Text;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                return result;
            return "[" + this.ID + "]";
        }
```

What you basically do is, you take the text in your Panel (which automatically gets inserted into a Literal child control by ASP.NET) and output it if there is no ViewState data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to do this.

- Create your control and have it extend `Panel`.
- In it's constructor or in the `OnInit()` method, set the `CssClass` property to a `roundedbox` style (or any other name).
- Add this style to your CSS and have it include `border-radius`.

For example:

```
.roundedbox {
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```